# How to prove this sequent using natural deduction?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

How do I prove
$$S\rightarrow \exists xP(x) \vdash \exists x(S\rightarrow P(x))$$
using natural deduction? Just an alignment of which axioms or rules that one could use would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is wrong as shown in the empty model with $S$ being false, where $S \to \exists x P(x)$ is true but $\exists x(S \to P(x))$ is false.

Comment: @KennyLau Natural deduction presumes a nonempty universe, both $(\forall x ~ \bot) \to \bot$ and $\top \to( \exists x ~ \top)$ are instances of inferences.

Comment: This seems like it isn't actually a constructively true statement.  Someone who knows kripke models can probably confirm.

Comment: @DanielV what does "constructively true" mean?

Comment: @KennyLau The short answer is "provable by constructive (intuitionistic) logic".  It is a type of proof where (among other things), statements of the form $\exists x ~ Px$ can only be proven by establishing an algorithm that constructs $x$, assuming all the assumptions are constructive as well.  So if you prove an $x$ exists, you can always demonstrate what that $x$ is.  Natural deduction without law-of-excluded-middle (or equivalent) is constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $S \to \exists x P(x)$ [P]
2. 1. $S$ [A]
   2. $S \to \exists x P(x)$ [1 R]
   3. $\exists x P(x)$ [2.2 2.1 $\to$E]
   4. 1. $P(a)$ [A]
      2. 1. $S$ [A]
         2. $P(a)$ [2.4.1 R]
      3. $S \to P(a)$ [2.4.2.1 2.4.2.2 $\to$I]
      4. $\exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [2.4.3 $\exists$I]
   5. $\exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [2.3 2.4.1 2.4.4 $\exists$E]
3. $S \to \exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [2.1 2.5 $\to$I]
4. 1. $\neg S$ [A]
   2. 1. $S$ [A]
      2. $\neg S$ [4.1 R]
      3. $\neg S \lor P(a)$ [4.2.2 $\lor$I]
      4. $P(a)$ [4.2.3 4.2.1 $\lor$E]
   3. $S \to P(a)$ [4.2.1 4.2.4 $\to$I]
   4. $\exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [4.3 $\exists$E]
5. $\neg S \to \exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [4.1 4.4 $\to$I]
6. $S \lor \neg S$ [LEM]
7. $\exists x [S \to P(x)]$ [3 5 6 $\lor$E]

How to complicate everything, take #314159.

Comment: Note that 6 [LEM] is classical, and 4.4 [4.3 $\exists$E] assumes a non-empty universe

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof in the Fitch formal proof system:

[image]

Comment: Is step 10 intuitionistic?

Comment: @KennyLau  I haven't really worked with intuitionistic logic, but from what little I gather about it, I believe step 10 would not be intuitionistic

Comment: Is this theorem intuitionistic?

Comment: @KennyLau Same answer: I'm not an expert in that particular area, but given as I saw no way to prove this without a proof by contradiction I don't think it is.